# Remove elasticity from webview

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview

I have a webview which I would like to remove the elasticity from. As it is now, when scrolling a page that is smaller than the webview, it will make an elasticity effect revealing the background underneath. I would like to remove this.

I have tried doing the following but without success. It finds the `WebDynamicScrollBarsView` but setting the elasticity of this, does not change anything.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSScrollView *scrollView = [self findScrollViewInSubviews:self.subviews];
    scrollView.horizontalScrollElasticity = NSScrollElasticityNone;
    scrollView.verticalScrollElasticity = NSScrollElasticityNone;
}

- (NSScrollView *)findScrollViewInSubviews:(NSArray *)subviews
{
    for (NSView *view in subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[NSScrollView class]])
            return (NSScrollView *) view;
        else
            return [self findScrollViewInSubviews:view.subviews];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Does anyone know how to remove the elasticity effect from a webview?

Comment: Oh, sorry! I'm deleting the answer.

Comment: The following should be working: `webView.mainFrame.frameView.documentView.enclosingScrollView.verticalScrollElasticity  = NSScrollElasticityNone;`

Comment: @Anne Sadly, that did not have any effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my subclass of WebView (or you can just do it directly, with `webView.mainFrame.frameView.documentView.enclosingScrollView`, but this makes it easier for me, personally)

```
// return the scroll view that we are currently using, if applicatble
- (NSScrollView *)mainScrollView {
    return [[[[self mainFrame] frameView] documentView] enclosingScrollView]; // can be nil
}
```

Then on finish load, as Anne noted literally as I was typing my answer :) ,

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    NSScrollView *mainScrollView = [sender mainScrollView];
    [mainScrollView setVerticalScrollElasticity:NSScrollElasticityNone]; 
    [mainScrollView setHorizontalScrollElasticity:NSScrollElasticityNone];
}
```

I'm not sure if doing it after the content has loaded is necessary, but I don't have my mac with me to try right now.

Comment: This needs to be done after the content has loaded, because it seems that it is reset inbetween didCommitLoadForFrame and didFinishLoadForFrame